# Why isn't my codeblock executing and displaying the output?

Tags: org-mode, babel

I have an org-mode file, with org-mode version 9+ (so my understanding is that Babel should be integrated). Then I have the following in the file

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports both :results output
return 7 + 7
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

I then compile to a PDF file. My understanding is that this should display both the codeblock and the evaluation of the codeblock. However the PDF just displays:

```
return 7 + 7
```

I have tried using `print` instead of return, but same outcome. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: this doesn't look like valid python. `return` is only used in a function

Comment: Good point, but as I said, I'd tried with `print` as well, which would have worked with `:results output`, as that reads from the stdout stream

Comment: What about `7 + 7` on its own?

Comment: have a look at worg: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html

Comment: I discovered I needed to just create an `init.el` file and load the language in there. Posted the answer below

Answer (score 3):

Only if you **use the header argument [`:results value`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-evaluation.html#_t_003aresults-value)** the code of the block is wrapped by a function and the result of the code block is the return value of that function.

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports both :results value
return 7 + 7
#+END_SRC
```

On the other hand [`:results output`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-evaluation.html#g_t_003aresults-output) means that the code of the block is sent to the interpreter. The result of the code block is what the code prints to the standard output.

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports both :results output
print "%d" % (7 + 7)
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Yeah, I also hadn't figured that out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I had misunderstood how the codeblocks were executed. You need an `init.el` file in `~/emacs.d/` and inside that I needed:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((python . t)))
```

Once this was in place, when I convert the file to a PDF, it gives the option to execute the code.